# My text size of a label won't change in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to add a label widget to my kv file but the text size won't change, as I understand it I think that the actual label size is changing because the label position should be at the bottom of the screen but it's in the middle of the screen when I run the script.

```
<LeftArea@FloatLayout>:


    Label:
        text: 'Search Term: '
        text_size: 200, 200
        size: 200, 200
        pos_hint: {'bottom': 1, 'left': 1}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK, I fixed it, I just used markup text

```
Label:
    markup: True
    text: '[size=20]Search Term: [/size]'
```

I still don't understand why my original code doesn't work if anyone can explain because I only followed the kivy docs.

Comment: To make your text bigger, use `font_size`, not `text_size`, because with the property you used is changed something [different](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.text_size).